# React - <optgroup> material UI by key

Tags: reactjs

That's what I'm getting from server -

```
{"id":1,"name":"jon","company":"fod"},
{"id":2,"name":"dan","company":"fod"},
{"id":3,"name":"fun","company":"fod"},
{"id":4,"name":"lol","company":"fod"},
{"id":5,"name":"hey","company":"god"}
```

I want to make a `<optgroup>` with metirial UI.

What I've found on the topic -

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/2671

But they don't use .map they define each group.

My code -

```
    <Select
      labelId="SelectLabel"
      id="Select"
      defaultValue=""
      value={props.state}
      label="select"
      onChange={props.SelectChangeHandler}
    >
      props.floorBrokersDataState?.map(
      ({ id, name, company }, index) => {
      return (
      <MenuItem key={index} value={id}>
        {name}
      </MenuItem>
    );
    }
   )}
   </Select>
```

How can I use `company` to be my group label - it should be disabled to click and contain all `name` inside of the group

Example -

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group your data by their `companyName` and then iterate over them. Here is an example of grouping your data by `companyName`:

```
const groupByCompany = (data) => {
  return Array.from(
    data.reduce((acc, item) => {
      const key = item.company;
      if (acc.has(key)) {
        acc.get(key).push(item);
      } else {
        acc.set(key, [item]);
      }
      return acc;
    }, new Map())
  );
};
```

I've implemented a material `Select` by your data here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xgbman